# Bokeh server_document script loads from IP (HTTP) but not from domain (HTTPS)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, bokeh, gunicorn

I have a Bokeh application embedded in Flask and Gunicorn (see [flask_gunicorn_embed.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_gunicorn_embed.py)). This works fine when I access everything through the IP address of the web server, but not when everything is proxied through Nginx. It will load everything from Flask, but not from Bokeh (the `autoload.js`).

---

#### Example:

I start Flask through Gunicorn with

```
gunicorn --workers 9 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --timeout 120 --log-file /some/directory/to/gunicorn/logs/gunicorn.log -m 0700 flask:app
```

I can now access everything from Flask through *http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000*. I have adapted the *flask_gunicorn_embed.py* and the most important bits are

```
script = server_document('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:%d/bkapp' % port, resources=None)
sockets, port = bind_sockets("0.0.0.0", 0)
bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado({'/bkapp': bkapp}, extra_websocket_origins=["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000"])
```

If I now access a page which uses this Bokeh server everything works fine. It loads

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:XXXXX/bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1001&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:XXXXX/bkapp&resources=none
```

and displays the graphs, and creates a web socket for callbacks.

---

This is **without** Nginx as a reverse proxy. I don't want to use the IP address of the web server because I need to use HTTPS, which requires a domain.

Thus I have the following Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name/;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /some/directory/to/flask/static;
    }
}
```

And I start Flask through Gunicorn with

```
gunicorn --workers 9 --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 --timeout 120 --log-file /some/directory/to/gunicorn/logs/gunicorn.log -m 0700 flask:app
```

I can now access everything from Flask through https://example.com. The *flask_gunicorn_embed.py* now looks like

```
script = server_document('https://example.com:%d/bkapp' % port, resources=None)
sockets, port = bind_sockets("0.0.0.0", 0)
bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado({'/bkapp': bkapp}, extra_websocket_origins=["example.com"])
```

However, every request that is generated through Bokeh's `server_document`

```
https://example.com:XXXXX/bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1001&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=https://example.com:XXXXX/bkapp&resources=none
```

results in either a *connection timed out* or a *connection refused* and thus not loading the scripts.

---

How can I make it such that it will connect and load the script?

It must have something to do with Nginx because if I request the file through the IP address it still works (due to the `bind_sockets("0.0.0.0", 0)`). But I cannot figure out what is causing this issue.

---

#### Edit:

It appears to be an issue with the fact that it uses HTTPS. My Nginx configuration is the same as the one given in the [Bokeh documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#reverse-proxying-with-nginx-and-ssl). The documentation says to use `--use_xheaders`, which is not possible because I am not using `bokeh serve`.

I do have

```
conf = {'use_xheaders': True}
bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado({'/bkapp': bkapp}, extra_websocket_origins=["example.com"], **conf)
bokeh_http = HTTPServer(bokeh_tornado, xheaders=True)
```

but it still won't load the scripts for HTTPS pages.

http://example_no_https.com will load the pages through the ports and https://example.com won't.

Answer (score 0):

`use_xheaders` is an argument for the Bokeh `Server` class (which passes it to a Tornado `HTTPServer`), not by `BokehTornado`. If you are not using `Server` because you are coordinating `BokehTornado` and an `HTTPServer` yourself, then you will have manually configure this option on the HTTP server, since you don't have a `Server` class doing it for you:

```
http_server_kwargs.setdefault('xheaders', opts.use_xheaders)
HTTPServer(..., **http_server_kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I edited the code but it still fails to connect/load the `autoload.js` file. It must have something to do with the port and Nginx failing to proxy it correctly because it won't complete the TLS handshake.

Comment: Or something else, because now it will just throw a connection refused error.